# getting rid of a middle cell of a FIFO structure

Tags: c, timeline, fifo

I'm using a FIFO structure to get a simplified version of a timeline. The problem is, when a message is liked, it has to go to the top of the structure again.

To do that, I thought on getting it out of the pile and piling it on top again, updating the number of likes.

unfortunately, I can't think of an easy way to get a cell in the middle of the FIFO structure to leave it.

on the timeline.h file:

```
typedef struct tipoConteudoMsg {
    int idUsuario;
    int idMsg;
    char msg[280];
    int tempo;
    int curtidas;
} tipoConteudoMsg;

typedef struct tipoMsg *apontadorTimeline;

typedef struct tipoMsg {
    tipoConteudoMsg cont; // content of the message;
    apontadorTimeline prox;
} tipoMsg; // celula

typedef struct tipoTimeline {
    apontadorTimeline fundo, topo;
    int tamanho;
} tipoTimeline; // pilha
```

I can get the pointer either to the cell that has the message ID that I need or the pointer to the cell that is right above it on the pile.

on timeline.c file in case people need to understand how I implemented the FIFO structure:

```
// fazTimelineVazia means "create empty timeline (FIFO structure)
void fazTimelineVazia (tipoTimeline *timeline) {
    timeline->topo = (apontadorTimeline) malloc(sizeof(tipoMsg));
    timeline->fundo = timeline->topo;
    timeline->topo->prox = NULL;
    timeline->tamanho = 0;
}

// empilhaTimeline means "pile message on top of the FIFO structure"
void empilhaTimeline (tipoTimeline *timeline, tipoConteudoMsg msg) {
    apontadorTimeline aux;

    aux = (apontadorTimeline) malloc(sizeof(tipoMsg));

    timeline->topo->cont = msg;
    aux->prox = timeline->topo;
    timeline->topo = aux;
    timeline->tamanho++;
}
```

Comment: If you need to reorder things, you shouldn't be using a FIFO in the first place.